# What SimpleDateFormat Pattern to use?

Tags: java, date, simpledateformat

I am receiving a date as a String from an API in the following format: `".expires": "Tue, 28 Apr 2015 06:17:40 GMT"`

Now I am trying to pass it to a `Date` variable in java:

```
public static Date getExpireDate(String date) {
        if (date != null || (date.length() == 0)) {
            //Date is not null or empty so continue
            try {
                SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
                Date dateNew = sdf.parse(date);
                return dateNew;
            }catch(Exception e){}
        }
        // return default timeout           
    }
```

Now I have found the following [documentation:](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

it has a simelar example which it presents a pattern like:
`EEE, d MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z`

However my time zone says just `GMT`. not `GMT -08`

What pattern will parse this string?

Comment: `EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss z` seems to work just fine for me

Comment: @MadProgrammer `hh` would be hours in 0-12, so I doubt it would work

Comment: @eis It worked okay for the value the OP provided ;)

Comment: oh SMALL `z` not big `Z`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work:

```
new SimpleDateFormat("EEE',' dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss z", Locale.US)
```

Lowercase 'z' is for `General time zone` wich is `Pacific Standard Time`or `PST` or `GMT-08:00`

Comment: @BasilBourque I know. But see the date of the answer. It was a time where java 8 was very new.

Comment: Yes, I saw the date, thus my use of the word "now". My comment is just a note to the readers of *today* so they know that, while correct, this Answer is now outmoded.

Answer (score 2):

## tl;dr

> What pattern will parse this string?

[`DateTimeFormatter.RFC_1123_DATE_TIME`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#RFC_1123_DATE_TIME)

> I am receiving a date as a String from an API in the following format: ".expires": "Tue, 28 Apr 2015 06:17:40 GMT"

Use only *java.time* classes.

```
ZonedDateTime
.parse(
    "Tue, 28 Apr 2015 06:17:40 GMT" ,
    DateTimeFormatter.RFC_1123_DATE_TIME
)
.toString()
```

> 2015-04-28T06:17:40Z

You can see that same moment adjusted into a time zone.

```
ZonedDateTime
.parse(
    "Tue, 28 Apr 2015 06:17:40 GMT" ,
    DateTimeFormatter.RFC_1123_DATE_TIME
)
.withZoneSameInstant(
    ZoneId.of( "America/Anchorage" ) 
)
.toString()
```

See this [code run live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/4ybveO).

> 2015-04-27T22:17:40-08:00[America/Anchorage]

## GMT -08?

Not sure what you meant.

`GMT` is basically the old way of saying an offset-from-UTC of zero hours-minutes-seconds. So there is no reason for your output to be eight hours behind UTC (`GMT -08`). You may be confused the fact that **`java.util.Date::toString` tells a lie**, dynamically applying the JVM’s current default time zone, thereby creating the illusion of a time zone in the `Date`. One of many reasons to never use these legacy date-time classes.

## RFC 1123 / RFC 822

Your input string `Tue, 28 Apr 2015 06:17:40 GMT` complies with [RFC 1123](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1123) (adapted from [RFC 822](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc822)). This format is now archaic.

## ISO 8601

Modern protocols instead adopt the [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) standard formats for date-time values represented as text.

## *java.time*

While the *java.time* classes built into Java use by default the ISO 8601 formats when parsing/generating strings, the `DateTimeFormatter` class carries a pre-defined formatter for this legacy format: [`DateTimeFormatter.RFC_1123_DATE_TIME`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#RFC_1123_DATE_TIME).

```
String input = "Tue, 28 Apr 2015 06:17:40 GMT" ;
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.RFC_1123_DATE_TIME ;
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.parse( input , f ) ;
```

See this [code run live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/4ybveO).

> zdt.toString(): 2015-04-28T06:17:40Z